# Overriding an implied database in a MySQL UNION?

Tags: mysql, select, union

I swear, this is for educational purposes only...

The MySQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
where name='value' AND addr='value' 
UNION SELECT * 
      FROM mysql.user;
```

But the error I get is that there is no `mysql.mytable table`.

Is there anything I can do in my union or in either of those values to make my query valid? Other than explicitly stating the `mytable` database name in the code? Let's assume I can't change anything in the query before the 'value'.

Comment: you query is wrong...that you want to do? ...there is no table like `mytable` and `user` in `information_schema`

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what are you trying to select from `information_schema.user`. `information_schema` is the standard MySQL database, it's there by default. However there is no `user` table in this database.

To view a list of your databases, do this in your MySQL console:

```
show databases;
```

To view tables in a database:

```
use information_schema
show tables;
```

From what you are saying, it looks like you are using `information_schema` database by default. Also you are trying to select `mytable` in this database, this table doesn't seem to exist either. Can you run the commands above and show us the output?

**Update:** If you need to select from two different databases:

```
select * from mydatabase.mytable union select * from mysql.users
```

Either remove `mydatabase` if `mytable` is in your current database or provide a proper name of your database instead. `mydatabase` here is just an example.

However, as already been pointed out to you, you should either have identical columns in both tables, or specify identical columns to be selected from each table.

Comment: Thanks maksimov. Sorry, I should have written mysql.user table instead of information_schema. The same issue exists. I get an error that there is no mysql.mytable, which is correct. mytable exists in some other database on the server.

Comment: Thanks maksimov, yes, I know that explicitly stating the database that mytable comes from will make that union work, but if that isn't there, is it impossible to make the query valid? If not, then this seems like "security by accident".

Comment: Clearly you are not selecting your database correctly before running this query. Query as you put it should run from the database where `mytable` exists (note how `mysql.user` is mentioned explicitely), however your error indicates that you are selecting `mysql` which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For functional and valid UNION clause, you must have the same columns in both queries. Missing columns in a select, highlight default NULL with aliases:

```
Select *, NULL as "column1" FROM table1 ...
```

Comment: Thank you throrin19, the number of columns isn't an issue, it's that MySQL assumes the mytable is in the same database as user, and it's not. So that's the error.